# How can I use isElementPresent(By by) method to verify my test script is working properly?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to use this code :

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by)
```

When I export my test script there will be automatically in the test script, but most of the method below is not used, so there will warnings stated that I'm not using that method..and my test script will be failed.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class cheesecake {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com.my/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testCheesecake() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("cheesecake");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.q.qs")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.mn-dwn-arw")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'News')]")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alert.getText();
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Can I know what is the use of all these methods and how to use it? Because, if I deleted them, my test script can run but even though I put a wrong password also can log in to the system.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, this is auto generated by the IDE but you have incorrectly edited it:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElements(by);
      return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
isElementPresent(By.id("J_idt16:J_idt30"));
```

It is there to make it easier to determine whether an element is visible on the page. Sometimes you want to have that element and do something with it, other times you just want to know if it's present or not. This is there to make it easy to do so.

If you are having problems with your test script, please post the code you are using and the HTML you are running against or try and reproduce it with a different public facing website.

Comment: I also get error for fail in below code 


public void tearDown() throws Exception {
       driver.quit();
       String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
       if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) 
       {
         fail(verificationErrorString);
       }
     }

Comment: seems something wrong in my public void tearDown() method..

fail(verificationErrorString) <---- got error here in eclipse said "The method fail(String) is undefined for the type login"

Comment: Remove the teardown method completely, it is doing nothing useful.

Comment: yes..It give me no more error after I remove the teardown method..so actually , when we need teardown ?

Comment: anyway thanks @Arran  :) ..do my code down here is correct ?means , the structure 

  public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
       try {
        isElementPresent(By.id("J_idt16:J_idt30"));
         return true;
       } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
         return false;
       }
     }
   
    public boolean isElementVisible(By id)
    {
     
     return driver.findElement(By.id("J_idt16:J_idt30")).isDisplayed();
     
    }

Comment: The teardown method you have is autogenerated by the IDE, and since you are not using it, you can remove it. As for your code, you have hardcoded `J_idt16:J_idt30` into it.